# Smaller binary relation on the set $\mathbb Q$

Tags: relations

Given two binary relations $R$ and $S$ over sets $A$ and $B$,then $R$ is said to be contained in $S$ if $$\forall a,b: (a,b) \in R \implies (a,b) \in S$$

Moreover $R$ is considered to be smaller than $S$ if $R$ is contained in $S$,but $S$ is not contained in $R$,e.g.$$R  ⊊ S$$

Wikipedia gives an example:

> On the rational numbers, the relation $>$ is smaller than $≥$, and equal to the composition $> ∘ >$.

I don't understand the  example,why $>$ is smaller than $≥$?

And what is the composition relation given by $> ∘ >$?

Comment: Can you prove that $>$ is contained in $\geq$? How about that $\geq$ is not contained in $>$? Hint: in the first part, let $a,b\in\mathbb Q$ such that $a>b$. For the second part, you need to find $a,b\in\mathbb Q$ such that $a\geq b$ but $a\not>b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand the example,why > is smaller than ≥?

If $a>b$ then we also have $a\geq b$, so $>$ is contained in $\geq$.  Additionally, $1$ is a rational number such that $1 \geq 1$ but $1\not>1$, so $>$ is smaller than $\geq$.

> And what is the composition relation given by >∘>?

By transitivity, $a > b$ and $b > c$ implies $a > c$ so it follows that $> \circ >$ is contained in $>$.  On the other hand, if $a>b$ where $a,b$ are rational, then $m = \frac{a+b}{2}$ is also rational and $a > m > b$, so $>$ is contained in $> \circ >$.  Therefore, $> \circ >$ equals $>$.

Comment: Yes, that $c$ was a typo.  Any rational number between $a$ and $b$ would work for $m$, but we need to pick one for the purposes of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that relation $\gt$ is smaller than $\geq$.

It translates to x $\gt$ y implies x $\geq$ y (and not the other way around). You can easily prove this as relations are just sets.

Composition of relations is a very interesting topic. It is a general form of composition of functions. Check out its definition [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Composition_of_relations#/Definition)

In this particular case, you can use the fact that there exists another rational number between any two different rational numbers.